# How to write a text file in removable disk in c#?

Tags: c#

How to write a text file in removable disk in c#?

```cs
            foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {                    
                        File.Create(drive);
                        MessageBox.Show("File Created");                 
                }
            }
```

Comment: _"How to write a text file in removable disk?"_ The same way you'd write a text file on a non-removable disk. See the [`File.WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext) method, for example..

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: You should create a file, not the drive itself

Comment: For the purposes of writing data, the `stream` can be the memory, a disk, a network etc.  The overall concepts are the same.  What specific issues are you having?

Comment: Do not write files in the root directory; that is not allowed to Standard users, and it has a bunch of nonintuitive reserved names. If this is a user file write to the user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Same as all other drives.

You can use [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8) method.

The `RootDirectory` property of [DriveInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo?view=netframework-4.8) is [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) object. You can use the `FullName` property as a root directory of the removable drive:

Code sample:

```
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(d.RootDirectory.FullName , "foo.txt"), "some_text");
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer using FullName property.

Comment: You can also use drive.name replace drive.RootDirectory.FullName to make the code simpler.